# What does the equation $W=RT(\ln V_1/V_2)$ mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, volume

I understand how this equation is derived but I do not know what it means. I understand $R$ can be taken to be work done by a ideal gas with a unit temperature increment. $T$ is the temperature (as a measure of kinetic energy) but I do not understand what $\ln V_1/V_2$ means.

Comment: W is the varying force of the ideal gas on the piston integrated over the differential displacements of the piston.  It's the same as $\int{Fds}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the work done by ideal gas at constant temperature or in an isothermal process.

The work done by an ideal gas is defined to be
$$W = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} P \, \text d V $$

Then, from the *Ideal Gas Law*, $PV = nRT.$

$$W = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{nRT}{V} \, \text d V $$

Since we are required to get the work done by the gas in isothermal process, not only n and R but also the temperature T are constant terms.

$$\begin{aligned} W &=nRT \int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{1}{V} \, \text d V \\
&= nRT \left[ \ln V \right]^{V_2}_{V_1} \\ &= nRT \ln \left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 0):

As @Chet Miller commented, the equation is derived from the basic equation for work in mechanics. That is

$$W=\int_{V1}^{V2}PdV$$

Can be derived from

$$W=\int_{s1}^{s2}Fds$$

As follows:

The pressure $P$ exerted by the piston of cross sectional area $A$ is related to the force $F$ by

$$F=PA$$

A differential displacement $ds$ of the piston is related to the differential change in volume $dV$ by

$$ds=\frac{dV}{A}$$

Substituting these into the second equation

$$W=\int(PA)\frac{dV}{A}=\int_{V1}^{V2}PdV$$

Which is the general equation for pressure-volume work for a closed system consisting of a gas enclosed by a cylinder fitted with a movable piston.

In order to evaluate this equation you need to know the process that takes you from the initial to final volume, i.e., you need to know how pressure varies with volume for a reversible constant temperature process involving an ideal gas. @Abl grp has shown you how that leads to the expression $\ln V1/V2$.

Hope this helps.